# Linux/Debian dpkg & administrator errors

Tags: debian, package-management, error-handling, chrome-book

So today I ran into a bunch of errors while using the **sudo** command on my **Chromebook** with **Linux** installed. For example when I try to remove my **Google Chrome beta** application, I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-beta
```

but I got this error:

```
(Reading database ... 81090 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing google-chrome-beta (74.0.3729.75-1) ...
Setting up 389-admin (1.1.43-1+b1) ...
Job for dirsrv-admin.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dirsrv-admin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dirsrv-admin, action "start" failed.
● dirsrv-admin.service - 389 Administration Server.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv-admin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-11 17:08:08 UTC; 39ms ago
  Process: 7507 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start -f /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin systemd[1]: Starting 389 Administration Server....
Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin apache2[7507]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified doma… message
Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin apache2[7507]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/dirsrv/…rror log
Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin apache2[7507]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin systemd[1]: Failed to start 389 Administration Server..
Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 11 17:08:08 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package 389-admin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of 389-ds-console:
 389-ds-console depends on 389-admin; however:
  Package 389-admin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package 389-ds-console (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 389-admin
 389-ds-console
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I even get that when I try updating my packages, like

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

any suggestions?

PS: I do not want to remove Chrome-beta, that is not my question. it is the error I'm trying to solve, because I get it when I try updating.

Another thing: when I type `apt-get install -f` this shows:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

So I type: `sudo apt-get install -f` and this shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  389-ds-console-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up 389-admin (1.1.43-1+b1) ...
Job for dirsrv-admin.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dirsrv-admin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dirsrv-admin, action "start" failed.
● dirsrv-admin.service - 389 Administration Server.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv-admin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-11 19:39:39 UTC; 46ms ago
  Process: 17449 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start -f /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 11 19:39:38 penguin systemd[1]: Starting 389 Administration Server....
Apr 11 19:39:39 penguin apache2[17449]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified dom… message
Apr 11 19:39:39 penguin apache2[17449]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/dirsrv…rror log
Apr 11 19:39:39 penguin apache2[17449]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Apr 11 19:39:39 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 11 19:39:39 penguin systemd[1]: Failed to start 389 Administration Server..
Apr 11 19:39:39 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 11 19:39:39 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package 389-admin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 389-admin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

then I tried `sudo dpkg --force-depends --configure 389-admin`
and it outputs:

```
Setting up 389-admin (1.1.43-1+b1) ...
Job for dirsrv-admin.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dirsrv-admin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dirsrv-admin, action "start" failed.
● dirsrv-admin.service - 389 Administration Server.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv-admin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-11 19:41:11 UTC; 43ms ago
  Process: 17507 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start -f /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin systemd[1]: Starting 389 Administration Server....
Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin apache2[17507]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified dom… message
Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin apache2[17507]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/dirsrv…rror log
Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin apache2[17507]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin systemd[1]: Failed to start 389 Administration Server..
Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 11 19:41:11 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package 389-admin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 389-admin
```

I also noticed that every time I run a command like `install`, `remove`, `upgrade` it does what it's supposed to do, but then it tries to setup 389-admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can reconfigure the package installation like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure 389-admin
```

And afterwards run back the uninstallation:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-beta
```

---

Alternatively, you can just remove it directly before uninstalling `google-chrome-beta`:

```
sudo dpkg -r 389-admin
```

Comment: when I typed the first command you said this happened: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of 389-admin:
 389-ds-console depends on 389-admin. And on the third one this happened: dpkg: error processing package 389-admin (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 389-admin

Comment: What happens if you type `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: it asks me if I have permission, so I typed sudo apt-get install -f and I got the same error as in my question

Comment: Could you try `sudo dpkg --force-depends --configure 389-admin`?

Comment: Setting up 389-admin (1.1.43-1+b1) ...
Job for dirsrv-admin.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dirsrv-admin.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dirsrv-admin, action "start" failed.
● dirsrv-admin.service - 389 Administration Server.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dirsrv-admin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   And I will post the other half:

Comment: other half: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-11 19:25:58 UTC; 35ms ago
  Process: 16176 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start -f /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 11 19:25:57 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Failed to reset devices.list: Operation not permitted
Apr 11 19:25:57 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Failed to set invocation ID on control group /system.slice/d…permitted
And the rest

Comment: The rest:
Apr 11 19:25:57 penguin systemd[1]: Starting 389 Administration Server....
Apr 11 19:25:57 penguin apache2[16176]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified dom… message
Apr 11 19:25:57 penguin apache2[16176]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/dirsrv…rror log
Apr 11 19:25:57 penguin apache2[16176]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Apr 11 19:25:58 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
And the end

Comment: The end: Apr 11 19:25:58 penguin systemd[1]: Failed to start 389 Administration Server..
Apr 11 19:25:58 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 11 19:25:58 penguin systemd[1]: dirsrv-admin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package 389-admin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 389-admin

Comment: Coud you edit the question with these information?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is working fine, that only tells the system to run `apt-get` as the superuser account (which it's doing). Your main issue is with a broken package installation (389-admin), which looks to be failing because there's a missing folder on the system that's preventing apache2 from running, apt can't continue until that package installation finishes. If you follow the instructions Paradox mentioned you should be able to correct the issue, but if it persists then you should look at what other packages are failing to install. Pay close attention to the error messages you're getting since they describe exactly what the problem is

```
dpkg: error processing package 389-admin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of 389-ds-console:
 389-ds-console depends on 389-admin; however:
  Package 389-admin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package 389-ds-console (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 389-admin
 389-ds-console
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment on the other answer yet, but based on your comment thread you need to remove or fix your broken packages (the easy route is just remove, so run `sudo apt-get remove 389-ds-console`)

As I said in my answer, look at the error messages you're getting, they're telling you exactly what is wrong and what you need to do.

Comment: And that gives me the exact same error as in my question :(

Comment: Then let's fix ds-console, look at the apache2 error, it's trying to find a non-existent directory. Open the file /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf and see what it is setting as the error directory, then create that directory and try `sudo systemctl start dirsrv-admin.service`. If that starts successfully (you can check the status with `sudo systemctl status dirsrv-admin.service`) then you should be able to use apt again.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, I know I can make a new dir by typing mkdir. but what should I name it to and etc?

Comment: You're going to need to check that configuration file, do you have a text editor you can use? Open up the file `/etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf` and look for the line that says `ErrorLog`, it'll tell you where the log folder needs to be.

Comment: Uh I don't think I have a text-editor.. it's a school-chromebook lol. But when I typed /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/http.conf it said: -bash: /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf: Permission denied.

Comment: I would highly suggest bringing the chromebook back to school and have someone there troubleshoot, you might end up making the situation far worse than it needs to be. Typing `/etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/http.conf` alone is telling Linux to literally run http.conf as a command. Also, your chromebook has a text editor built in as do all Linux distributions, but I would highly suggest not using it. If you want to try to continue troubleshooting you can use the command `less`. So you would do `less /etc/dirsrv/admin-serv/httpd.conf` and do a search (press `/`) for `ErrorLog`, then press `q` to quit.